# Walk through a directory, alter delimiter and change the file extension

Tags: python, csv

Just as the title states, I'm trying to walk through a directory of files that are .tsv, I want to change the delimiter from tab to "|" and change the extension to .csv. When I run this from command line and pass in the file path, old extension and new extension (e.g. "For example: convert.py C:/Users/MyDir/files .tsv .csv") I get the error: "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified".

Here is my current code:

```
import csv
import sys
import os

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
     sys.exit("Usage: convert_to_psv.py ~/dir .tsv .csv")
else:    
     cur_dir = (sys.argv[1])
     old_ext = (sys.argv[2])
     new_ext = (sys.argv[3])
     print "here1"
     files = os.listdir(cur_dir)
     for filename in files:
         file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
         if old_ext == file_ext:
             newfile = filename.replace(old_ext, new_ext)
             os.rename(filename, newfile)
             csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
             csv.writer(file(sys.argv[3], 'w+'), delimiter="|").writerows(csv.reader(open(sys.argv[2]), delimiter="\t"))
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read and write the same file at the same time; you'd either have to read everything into memory, or use a separate output file.

The easiest way would be to *not* rename the file, but to write to the new filename instead, and then *delete* the old file:

```
import csv
import sys
import os

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
     sys.exit("Usage: convert_to_psv.py ~/dir .tsv .csv")
else:    
     cur_dir, old_ext, new_ext = sys.argv[1:]
     for filename in os.listdir(cur_dir):
         filename = os.path.join(cur_dir, filename)
         base, file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
         if file_ext == old_ext:
             newfile = base + new_ext
             csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
             with open(filename, 'rb') as ifh, open(newfile, 'wb') as ofh:
                 reader = csv.reader(ifh, delimiter='\t')
                 csv.writer(ofh, delimiter='|').writerows(reader)
             os.unlink(filename)
```

Note that this doesn't necessarily create the new file with the same permissions.

Comment: You probably want `csv.writer(ofh, delimiter='|').writerows(reader)`. Also might be best to leave the `unlink()` out at least until you're sure it works. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, yes that was a typo. The original version trashed data for sure, so let's hope the OP took backups. :-)

Comment: Ha! first thing I did was copy my files to a new directory. Thanks dudes. I'll report back as soon as I test this.

Comment: So I'm getting an error at line 14:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as ifh, open(newfile, 'wb') as ofh:"No such file or directory : 'first.tsv'"
It hangs on the very first .tsv in the file. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2338089: fixed, `os.listdir()` only gives relative names, not paths.